# AES CTR 128 Decryption with key and iv values using CryptoJs Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to decrypt the below message which has been encrypted using AES CTR 128(The encryption is done in PHP need to decrypt in Javascript).

```
const message = "DEnw6dO5nEZ4k532f3I8U6Vy1m/kgeqZhPAUqjVwCDwBRTUcxkgSn95ROXdy3lPF7ybbIiDIUYtmfru6AaNvUlP9HxOdlMkjSJDMDz7pcDj+Hqioipp/hqfSqPfSkFI8Q+VkBV9b2zNy9lamy4NmaFBo03KvVm3Hw2cMWHeRgE8DTJYPoYrBqIlKJ3PT7E3edd433UGRC/wdZ1jkf1cgpD3HdMHDDRtLnA2q/mbmuYHs7hZSz+CLzBHP6iq4+jEO/6FrLCQSPXqEwyRvTQ73ngS1KOoI5LdhQV7s7vrKJcxHWEBX5A84F7VRo+at/0aE0m71GwmHvJSs5ZrLCkuiLKHqyzO4SUHNeP0f1VqQmuphC0o8M912xfquBI9tv0TIipbvw2hNKKL66tYCBSx8W0C6rodJ+yirHs+Q5CorBqzrYr28it3gqs0bHrkN7A=="

const key = "AJ89HFJHAJ89HFJH"
        
const iv = "hsjsjdkdueooqpjj"

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR })

console.log("Here is decrypted",decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

After this I am getting below error message in console

[image]

Below is the PHP code which has been used

```
$encryption_text = openssl_encrypt($text, $crypto_details['ciphering'], $crypto_details['cryptokey'], $crypto_details['option'], $crypto_details['iv']);
```

Checked multiple resources but not able to find correct solution for this please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Decryption is not possible with AES-128/CTR (at least it does not result in data that is UTF8 decodable). You can verify this e.g. with https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/.  Post the PHP code that was used for encryption.

Comment: @Topaco I have added PHP code please check.

Comment: Also with the decryption counterpart of the posted PHP code no decryption is possible. Your data seems to be inconsistent. Post all missing data: `$text`, `$crypto_details['option']`,... so that your ciphertext is reproducible with the PHP code.

Comment: @Topaco the encryption and decryption is working fine in php code but not working using CryptoJS.

Comment: No, your ciphertext cannot be decrypted even with PHP. Here is the proof: https://paiza.io/projects/FwjbCnMU-dHT4w5f3oYZqA. If you disagree, post complete test data proving that your data is decryptable with PHP.

Comment: You need to disable padding on the CryptoJS side for stream cipher modes (unlike most libraries, CryptoJS doesn't do this implicitly). Then decryption works (at least decryption of *valid* data).